# Cannot install Ubuntu 16.04.1 - video mode problem

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, video, display

I want to install Ubuntu for some developement projects. I have created an USB Live Disk with Rufus and Universal USB Installer, but for some reason, at some point, before entering the installation screen (I pass the boot menu selection and the ubuntu violet loading screen) I get the following error from my Display saying:

"CANNOT DISPLAY THIS VIDEO MODE, CHANGE COMPUTER DISPLAY INPUT TO 1920X1080@60HZ"

My rig spec:

Philips 1900x1200 Display

CPU: AMD FX8300

GPU: ZOTAC GTX950

MOTHERBOARD Gigabyte 970A-DS3P V3

I suspect it's something with the grub cfg file... I tried everything related to this after some research here and other linux forums, but none seemed to work.

Comment: When options menu appears, and before you select to install ubuntu, select nomodeset. Other option is to install without graphical interface (which mean ubuntu server, or some lighter gui, like lubuntu), and then install ubuntu desktop from there.

Comment: Thank you! Although i didn't find that F6 button to change the nomodeset, i pressed 'e' in the GRUB menu and added "nomodeset quiet splash" and it worked!

Comment: Glad to help, I'll add this as an answer because it works.

Answer (score 2):

When options menu appears, and before you select to install ubuntu, select nomodeset after presing F6 button.
From the [UbuntuAnswers](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132):

> The newest kernels have moved the video mode setting into the kernel. So all the programming of the hardware specific clock rates and registers on the video card happen in the kernel rather than in the X driver when the X server starts.. This makes it possible to have high resolution nice looking splash (boot) screens and flicker free transitions from boot splash to login screen. Unfortunately, on some cards this doesnt work properly and you end up with a black screen. Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

Other option is to install without graphical interface (which mean ubuntu server, or some lighter gui, like lubuntu), and then install ubuntu desktop from there.